# Angular 5+ Two Methods for Component Communication and Possible Issues

Tags: angular, rxjs

Here are two Stackblitz projects that show component communication.

Update: Thought I could embed the Stackblitz's editor but no go.

**Method 1**: Simply uses an array from a service:

data.service.ts:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  people: Array<any> = [
    { name: 'David', role: 'King of Israel' },
    { name: 'Daniel', role: 'Major Prophet' }
  ];

  state = {
    msg: ''
  }

  constructor() { console.log(this.people) }

}
```

app.component.ts:

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
    })

    export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

      people: Array<Object>;
      state;

     constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.people = this.dataService.people;
        this.state = this.dataService.state; 
      }

      load() {
         this.dataService.people.push({name: 'Obadiah', role: 'Minor Prophet'});
      }

    }
```

app.component.html

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let person of people">{{person.name}}  |  {{person.role}}</li>
</ul>

<button (click)="load()">Load Additional Data</button>

<pre>{{state.msg}}</pre>
```

**Method 2:** Uses RxJS Subjects provided by the service.

data.service.ts:

```js
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  url = 'http://localhost:3000/Data';
  dataStream$ = new Subject<MyModel[]>();
  messages: string[] = [];
  subscription;

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Cache-control': 'no-cache'})
  };

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  get() {
    this.subscription = this.http.get<any[]>(this.url).subscribe(data => this.dataStream$.next(data));
  }

  post(obj: MyModel) {
    this.subscription = this.http.post<any>(this.url, obj, this.httpOptions)
    .subscribe(res => this.get(),  err => this.messages.push(err),
    () => this.messages.push(`'${obj.title}' added`));
  }
```

}

app.component.ts

```js
  @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

      dataStream$ = new Subject<any>();
      messages: string[] = [];

      obj = {
        title: 'Epsilon',
        body: 'Lorem ipsum...'
      }

      constructor(private dataService: DataService) {} 

      ngOnInit() {
        this.dataStream$ = this.dataService.dataStream$;
        this.dataService.get();
        this.messages = this.dataService.messages;
      }

      post(){ 
        this.dataService.post(this.obj); 
      }

    }
```

app.component.html:

```html
 <pre>Messages: {{ messages | json }}</pre>
 <pre>Data:{{ dataStream$ | async | json }}</pre>
 <button (click)="post()">Add Post</button>
```

I need to know if either of these methods are preferred and why.

Is using RxJS in this manner overkill?

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Code added. Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one of the benefits with Reactive function programming is to ensure purity of the data and easier to trace where the mutation of data is happening. This is really about declarative vs imperative programming approach.

First approach is easier to code, since you don't have to care about when and where the data is pushed, other component can update the properties sliently this.dataService.people=[a,b,c] without notification to any component.

Second approach (although can be written better), data is contained in stream and there's only one entry point to the data providing that the code is solid, It less prone to error.

Having said that the learning curve is quite steep (do it properly e.g chainning, slicing combine chain, error handling, handle async) for the second approach.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Need clarification on: "other component can update the properties silently this.dataService.people=[a,b,c] without notification to any component" Because any component that has a property associated with that array will know about the updated array - at least the component's view would know.  And clarify: "Second approach...data is contained in stream and there's only one entry point to the data".

Comment: yes the component will render the array correctly. but in the case of any error integrity issue it happens silently. I can inject your service and update it any where in any component, unless you delibrately put a setter function in dataservice, or it is hard to trace where it happens. It is a general issue with OO state management, if not done right.

Comment: Thanks again. How about clarification on "Second approach...only one entry point." Also, I'm definitely open to writing it better if you're willing to share.

Comment: Your second approach the data are encapsulated in datastream$, the only way to mutate it is to trigger the get api call. Data change can be monitored and tracked easily.

Comment: yes you are correct. Approach two is to maintain a single source of truth. An even better idea for approach two is to .next() an immutable object e.g [].concat(data), sometimes we also mutate the data by reference without knowing.

Comment: Could you expand on "better idea for approach two is to .next() an immutable object e.g [].concat(data)". Also, my last comment (deleted) is erroneous as I made it sound like the first method  didn’t need the service injected. In either method the service would need to be injected in order for any component to make a change to the data, therefore it’s still possible to track where the changes are coming from in either case.

Comment: take a look here https://wecodetheweb.com/2016/02/12/immutable-javascript-using-es6-and-beyond/ 
for immutability. And yes you still need to inject service but variable mutations are much more clear with reactive functional fashion. if you have a data structure with OO like data=[{foo:'bar'}]; var a=data; a.foo='mutated', data get changed sliently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171021/discussion-between-jeremiah2911-and-fan-cheung).